# How to insert an exisiting IF statement into a ISBLANK formula

Tags: excel, formula

I have an existing formula of =IF(AND(H21>F21,H21<G21),"PASS","FAIL") that tells an inspector whether the measured values (H21) are pass or fail when compared to the min (F21) and max (G21) allowable dimensions. This works well apart from when there isn't a measured value on an unused line it results in a fail as it sees a blank cell as less than the min. How can I incorporate the ISBLANK function into this exisiting formula?

Comment: What result do you want to display when `ISBLANK()` is true?

Comment: I want result to show a blank if the measured result is blank so that rows without inspection measurements do not still show up as FAIL.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can add another `IF`:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(H2),"",IF(AND(H2>F2,H2<G2),"PASS","FAIL"))
```

but I think `CHOOSE` would be easier to expand if new parameters were added:

```
=CHOOSE((H2<>"")*((H2>F2)+(H2<G2))+1,"","FAIL","PASS")
```

[image]